# Accelerometer reading in Android App on ChromeOS. #AndroidAppsOnChromeOS

Tags: android, androidappsonchromeos

Is there anyway to use accelerometer in sideloaded APK to ChromeOS?

I have an ASUS Chromebook Flip. I tried reading accelerometer with an HTML5 page on Chrome, and it works normally, but a sideloaded APK contained a webview with the same HTML5 page, the accelerometer reading doesn't work. I tried adding:


to the Manifest file, but no result.

I also tried several Android games that require accelerometer, or Android apps that read sensor, none can read Chrome OS accelerometer or gyroscope.

Please help, thanks.﻿